# Display Folders and Files in ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms, treeview

I created a function in a Windows Form Application that allows users to view a folder structure (TreeForm) and the files within the folders in a ListView.  Now, I need to create the same function for a WebForm application.  I attempted to use the same code but have found that the asp.net webform controls do not contain the same properties as the winform.  Below is part of the code which I cannot determine how to convert so that it maybe used with on a webform page.  Does anyone now how to convert the following code so that it can be used with an asp.net webform?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
    protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ListView1.Items.Clear();
        ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[] subItems;
        List<string> permittedFoldersFiles = new List<string>();

        if (permittedFoldersFiles.Contains(dir.Name))
        {
            item = new ListViewItem(dir.Name, 0);
            subItems = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]
                    {new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "Directory"), 
                    new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, 
                    dir.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString())};
            item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use this sample it's work very well

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                DirectoryInfo rootInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/MyFolder/"));
                this.PopulateTreeView(rootInfo, null);
            }
        }

        private void PopulateTreeView(DirectoryInfo dirInfo, TreeNode treeNode)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
            {
                TreeNode directoryNode = new TreeNode
                {
                    Text = directory.Name,
                    Value = directory.FullName
                };

                if (treeNode == null)
                {
                    //If Root Node, add to TreeView.
                    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(directoryNode);
                }
                else
                {
                    //If Child Node, add to Parent Node.
                    treeNode.ChildNodes.Add(directoryNode);
                }

                //Get all files in the Directory.
                foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
                {
                    //Add each file as Child Node.
                    TreeNode fileNode = new TreeNode
                    {
                        Text = file.Name,
                        Value = file.FullName,
                        Target = "_blank",
                        NavigateUrl = (new Uri(Server.MapPath("~/"))).MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(file.FullName)).ToString()
                    };
                    directoryNode.ChildNodes.Add(fileNode);
                }

                PopulateTreeView(directory, directoryNode);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your answer provided the basic concept to build an asp.net file browser treeview, thank you for your time!